# Locking a Hash Map when Rehashing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, hashmap, mutex

I'm trying to create a hash map that is thread-safe. I have a vector of mutexes for each bucket in the hash map to support a reader-writer lock for each entry in the hash map.

However, when I want to rehash the hash map, I want to lock the whole map so that no reads/writes can occur during rehashing.

I think I need an additional mutex, however do my Gets/Puts methods also need to acquire this mutex? How do I block other threads from doing Reads/Writes only when rehashing is occurring and not block each other when only writing and reading is happening?

This is how my current hash table class looks:

```
template<typename K, typename T>
class HashTable {
    int num_buckets_;
    double threshold_ratio_;
    int num_elements_;
    vector<vector<pair<T, K>>> table_;
    vector<mutex> read_write_locks_;
    mutex mu_;

    int GetHash(const K& key) {
        return hash<K>{}(key) % num_buckets_;
    }

    void Rehash() {
        scoped_lock<mutex> lock(mu_);   // Lock the whole table?
        cout << "Threshold Value has been reached. Rehashing...\n";

        vector<vector<T>> new_table(2 * num_buckets_);
        num_buckets_ = 2 * num_buckets_;

        vector<mutex> new_mutexes(2 * num_buckets_);
        read_write_locks_.swap(new_mutexes);
        // TODO : Implementation
    }

public:
    explicit HashTable(int num_buckets) : num_buckets_(num_buckets), threshold_ratio_(0.75), num_elements_(0) {
        table_.resize(num_buckets);
        vector<mutex> temp(num_buckets);
        read_write_locks_.swap(temp);
    }

    void Put(const K& key, const T& val) {
        ++num_elements_;
        if (static_cast<double>(num_elements_) / num_buckets_ > threshold_ratio_) {
            Rehash();
        }
        int hash_val = GetHash(key);
        scoped_lock<mutex> write_lock(read_write_locks_[hash_val]);
        cout << "Putting Key: " << key << ", Hash: "<< hash_val << "  with Value: " << val << '\n';
        table_[hash_val].push_back({val, key}); //TODO: For existing keys it should replace the value, not create a new entry
    }

    T Get(const K& key) {
        int hash_val = GetHash(key);
        scoped_lock<mutex> read_lock(read_write_locks_[hash_val]);

        if (table_[hash_val].size() >= 1) {
            for (const auto& elem : table_[hash_val]) {
                if (elem.second == key) {
                    cout << "Key: " << key << " gets value: " << elem.first << '\n';
                    return elem.first;
                }
            }
        }
        cerr << "Unable to find key in hash table. Terminating Program. \n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to build thread-safety into the HashTable class itself?  There are several reasons why it's considered a bad idea:  (1) it will make your HashTable less efficient than it otherwise would be for cases where it isn't being concurrently accessed by multiple threads, and (2) it doesn't adequately solve the thread-safety issue anyway (e.g. consider if thread A needs to place several items into the HashTable such that thread B would either 'see' none of them in the table or all of them -- to implement that, the calling code would need to lock an external mutex anyway)

Comment: Yeah you do make valid points and I can now understand why it would be a bad idea, I was mainly trying to do this for learning purposes.

Comment: I think this is a very good exercise but not necessarily efficient, nor a practical design.

If you have all your mutexes in contiguous memory (`std::vector`), then it _may_ not necessarily be cache-friendly when you have one thread that wants to acquire a mutex, and another thread that wants to acquire another adjacent mutex. Your processor _may_ end up reloading the same cache line.

On some implementations, `std::mutex` is 40 bytes in size, so it wouldn't matter, I guess?

For more [details](https://meribold.org/2017/10/20/survey-of-cpu-caches/),  see the section on cache lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is overthinking. A single mutex protecting the entire container should be sufficient. But if you insist on implementing this kind of a complicated design:

1. Use a `std::shared_mutex` for your global container mutex.
2. The individual getters/putters will need to acquire a shared lock on the global mutex, before locking their individual hash buckets.
3. Rehash acquires an exclusive lock, which blocks all getters/putters.

Comment: `std::shared_mutex` was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if we dedicate one thread to doing that. Now of course you can then get rid of the "global" shared mutex if you have that thread acquire all of the buffer's mutexes, i.e "read_write_locks_" whenever it needs to rehash.